# How to simulate a key up Event from an input in an Angular -cli 4 unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angular-cli, angular

In vanilla JS you can simulate a key up on an input by doing:

```
testComponent.dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"))
```

However doing this in the angular-cli unit test or in the console doesn't trigger this function in my [component](https://github.com/QuantumInformation/money-input/blob/master/src/money-input.ts#L16), which responds to key events by:

```
  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

You should create an event

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
      bubbles : true, cancelable : true, shiftKey : false
});
```

And then get the reference of the debugElement using css selector

```
const input = debugElement.query(By.css('#id_of_element'));
```

And then reference of native html element from the previous one

```
const inputElement = input.nativeElement;
```

Assign the value for the native element as , now the text field value contains 12.

```
inputElement.value = 12;
```

finally dispatch the key up event

```
inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

it will trigger the function

Dont forget to add the following line in before each and make sure you define debugElement

```
debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I my case somehow value was empty to I had to explicitly define it:

```
function generateKeyUpEvent(value: string): KeyboardEvent {
    const event: KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', { value: { value } });
    return event;
}
```

and then despatch in my test case:

```
component.input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(generateKeyUpEvent('a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my component I have

```html
<textarea [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswer" (keyup)="textAnswerChanged()"></textarea>
```

I needed to test that typing in the field will call a service method which is called from `textAnswerChanged()`.  Just dispatching a `keyup` event is not enough to trigger the `ngModel` to change.  You must dispatch 2 events.

- `KeyboardEvent('input')` - causes `ngModel` to update
- `KeyboardEvent('keyup')` - causes `(keyup)` on the `<textarea>` to fire

```ts
it('should update the selected answer when a value is typed', () => {
  const textArea = element.querySelector('textarea') as HTMLTextAreaElement;

  spyOn(injectedExampleSvc, 'changeAnswer');
  
  //no selection initially
  expect(component.selectedAnswer).toBeUndefined();

  textArea.value = 'foo';
  textArea.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('input'));
  textArea.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup'));
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(component.selectedAnswer).toEqual('foo');
  expect(injectedExampleSvc.changeAnswer).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```